# trigger multiple elements using tween using same class

Tags: javascript, animation, scrollmagic

i will be using multiple svg lines for this and would basically need this code to be able to use the same trigger class for 5 svg lines. Just not sure how i would go about doing this. any help would be appreciated. hope this make sense..

```
<div id="trigger1"></div>
  <svg height="550" width="500">
  <line class="draw" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%" 
   style="stroke:rgb(128,128,128);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>

function pathPrepare ($el) {
    var lineLength = $el[0].getTotalLength();
    $el.css("stroke-dasharray", lineLength);
    $el.css("stroke-dashoffset", lineLength);
}

var $draw = $("line.draw");

// prepare SVG
pathPrepare($draw);
// build tween
var tween = new TimelineMax()
    .add(TweenMax.to($draw, 0.9, {strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone})) // draw word for 0.9


// build scene
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: '#trigger1', duration: 500, tweenChanges: true})
                .setTween(tween)
                .addIndicators() 
                .addTo(controller);
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question and give some more info on what is the input and expected behaviour. Right now it's pretty hard to understand the question

Comment: yeah sorry hard to explain. using the script above when triggered a SVG line will draw down the center of the page until section ends. that is setup and works but i have 5 SVG lines doing the same thing but should not happen till triggered. i basically want to be able to use the scripts above so each SVG has its own trigger but with out having to repeat this code 5 times.

Comment: here is a over the top example https://www.primelending.com/about-us/process/ . basically what the line is doing

Comment: So where are the rest of the lines? can you include the markup for that too

Comment: ok got it. So you have different sections and different trigger points

Comment: yes correct! sorry for the confusion. if you take the svg above and duplicate 5 times but in different sections thats exactly what it is. i am assuming i would use a each function and set the triggerElement to "this" but im struggling..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove duplication you can do this

```
$(".trigger").each(function(){      
    var $draw = $(this).find("line.draw");
    pathPrepare($draw); 
    // build tween
var tween = new TimelineMax()
    .add(TweenMax.to($draw, 0.9, {strokeDashoffset: 0, ease:Linear.easeNone})) // draw word for 0.9

    new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: $(this)[0], duration: 500, tweenChanges: true})
                .setTween(tween)
                .addIndicators() 
                .addTo(controller);

})
```

Assuming I have markup like this

```
<div id="trigger1" class="trigger">

    <svg height="550" width="500">
  <line class="draw" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%" 
   style="stroke:rgb(128,128,128);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>

</div>

<div id="trigger2" class="trigger">

    <svg height="550" width="500">
  <line class="draw" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%" 
   style="stroke:rgb(128,128,128);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>

</div>
<div id="trigger3" class="trigger">

    <svg height="550" width="500">
  <line class="draw" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%" 
   style="stroke:rgb(128,128,128);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>

</div>
```

Hope this helps. But you can only go to a certain extent like this if you want to control the directions of the line then you might need to edit the pathPrepare function based on the trigger section.

https://codepen.io/srajagop/pen/GaZbrW?editors=0010

Comment: sorry for the confusion early on!